# Can I use a question mark for a list after a colon?

Tags: lists, colons, question-mark

For example,

> After the incident, I was no longer sure who to blame: Ethan, Michael,
> or Jake?

Or is there a better way to phrase this sentence?

Comment: Why do you need a question mark at all? This sentence is formatted as a declarative, and its purpose appears to be simply to provide information to the reader. I would just use a period.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Maybe a better example might be: *Who should I blame: ...?*

Comment: And even as written, I can understand the urge to use a question mark, because it's expressing a question in the speaker's mind. It feels like "should it be" is elided before the list.

Comment: Yes, with "who(m) should I blame", I'd include a question-mark at the end, because it is certainly asking a question (and is in a typical interrogative form). I'm not aware of any rule mandating a period after a colon.